# How do I redirect specific item to a specific site

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc

Is there any way to redirect chosen item to a specific site?
[Here's a pic that would help me explaining the problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YtThE.png)

Whenever the Price button on a Book with title1 and author1 I would like it to send me to site1
and whenever Price button on a Book with title2 and author2 is clicked I would like it to send to site2.
Here is the hyperlink code:

```
<a href="#?id=@item.Id" style="margin:0 10px"> Price </a>
```

What are the best ways to make this happen? I can provide more code if needed.

Answer (score 0):

If we are talking about two different sites, you can think of it as two different endpoints, so using `href attribute` won't help you. If you know the path of the second endpoint (seems like a usual controller's actions), you can use different techniques to send a request:

- back-end: create a controller's action - something like Price(int id) and then use `HttpRequestMessage` and `HttpClient` for sending request. See example: (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/http-requests?view=aspnetcore-6.0#basic-usage)
- front-end: making an event on button click and send request with fetch(). FetchAPI explained in the following link (https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch)